# Why isn't my function (using multithreading) correctly taking the average?

Tags: c, multithreading, average

The relevant part of the code is this:

```
void *calculate_average(void *param)
{
        int count = *(int *)param;
    int i;
    double sum;

    average = 0.000000;

    for (i=1l; i<count; i++)
        sum += list[i];
    
    average = (double)(sum / count);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

The only purpose of this function is to take an average of numbers stored in the list, and assign that value to the double average, which is managed and eventually returned by the parent thread. The list of numbers is entered on the invocation of the program and immediately stored in the list.

An example case is the set of numbers {54 15 25 45 60 93 68 57}. This set of numbers has the average 52.125. The program, when run, outputs an average of 45.375. We're required to use the gcc compiler, so it's not as if I have a full debug suite available for use. I'm unsure of the full nature of the issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The posted code cannot be compiled and executed as there are no `#include` directives and  there is no `main()` method.  So it's impossible for anyone to say why it isn't working, as they can't test.

Comment: `double sum;` has not been initialised. So `sum += list[i];` is *undefined behaviour*. If nothing else, you'll need `double sum = 0;`. It is strange code though, using a mix of local and global and argument variables, and this `i=1l` is unusual because `i` is `int`.

Comment: additionally, is the calling thread waiting on the worker thread to finish? _it's not as if I have a full debug suit available for use_ . Take a look at gdb.

Comment: `int count = *(int *)param;` is suspicious as well.  It's not necessarily wrong, but it's suggestive of one of the common errors that people make when starting threads.  We can't tell whether you are making that error, however, because you haven't shown how you start the threads.

Comment: One common error is passing a pointer to a "local" variable that promptly goes out of scope.

Comment: Tip: It's clearer to use `NULL` instead of `0` to mean a NULL pointer.

Comment: Tip: `return ...;` can be used instead of `pthread_exit( ... );`.

Comment: Tip: `1` creates an `int`. `1l` creates a `long`. So why are you using `1l`?

Comment: Tip: Don't use unnecessary casts, such as the one in `average = (double)(sum / count)`. They can hide introduce and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, you're using global and local variables, not wrong but error-prone. As you can pass an argument to the thread starting function, making good use of it, is of huge benefit.

e.g.

```
//data struct which is used to provide a thread function
//with a range of data and a field called 'average' to return
//the result
struct thread_data {
    int *begin; //inclusive
    int *end;   //exclusive
    double average; //result
};

void* calculate_average(void *param)
{
    struct thread_data *data = param; //cast
    int sum = 0; //initialize with 0
    for (int *ptr = data->begin; ptr < data->end; ++ptr) //for each element
        sum += *ptr; //add element value to sum
    data->average = (double) sum / (data->end - data->begin); //take the average
    return NULL; //return NULL or some other meaningful value
}

int main()
{
    int *arr; //some int values
    struct thread_data data[] = { //create partitions
        {.begin = arr,     .end = arr + n},
        {.begin = arr + n, .end = arr + m},
        /* ... */
    };
    //then for each thread, pass &data[i] as argument 
    //to the thread starting function
    //e.g. pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, calculate_average, &data[i]);
}
```

As you can see, no global variables are used, therefore no data race conditions. The list has been partitioned and passed separately to the individual threads. Each data partition has its own `average` field, which then can be used to take the average of the whole list.

Comment: `(struct thread_data*) param; //cast`?  Casting to/from `void *` is not necessary in C.

Comment: I was more wondering why the value wasn't being calculated property. I really don't think it was a result of race conditions, since the thread isn't actually modifying the list. However, this answer still helped me solve the issue. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Bad habits, what should i say? Thanks for the notice, already corrected.

Comment: @Drift476 No you've already had the correct answer, `sum` wasn't initialized properly (or at all).But i hope you realize, that your code has some other issues, which should be dealt with, aka corrected. Otherwise, they will detain as 'bad habits'.